# Optimize Rust function for certain likely parameter values

Tags: rust

Is it possible to ask the compiler to optimize the code if I know that the domain of a certain parameter will likely be among a few select values?

eg.

```
// x will be within 1..10
fn foo(x: u32, y: u32) -> u32 {
   // some logic
}
```

The above function should be compiled into

```
fn foo(x: u32, y: u32) -> u32 {
    match x {
        1 => foo1(y), // foo1 is generated by the compiler from foo, optimized for when x == 1
        2 => foo2(y), // foo2 is generated by the compiler from foo, optimized for when x == 2
        ...
        10 => foo10(y),
        _ => foo_default(x, y) // unoptimized foo logic 
    }
}
```

I would like the compiler to generate the above rewrite based on some hint.

Comment: Hard to say without a real example.

Comment: The only thing I could think to communicate that to the compiler is by branching with [`likely`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/intrinsics/fn.likely.html)/[`unlikely`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/intrinsics/fn.unlikely.html) or with some application of [`#[cold]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes/codegen.html#the-cold-attribute) but you'd have to inspect the generated code to see if that's made an impact.

Comment: Even if the compiler understands the domain, doing the above transformation might be a regression due to code bloat.

Comment: @kmdreko if the compiler thinks that it's not worth doing the above transformation, that is fine by me but I'd like to help the compiler make that decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the logic in a `#[inline(always)]` `foo_impl()`, then call it with the values you expect:

```rust
// x will be within 1..10
#[inline(always)]
fn foo_impl(x: u32, y: u32) -> u32 {
   // some logic
}

fn foo(x: u32, y: u32) -> u32 {
    match x {
        1 => foo_impl(1, y),
        2 => foo_impl(2, y),
        // ...
        10 => foo_impl(10, y),
        _ => foo_impl(x, y),
    }
}
```

Because of the `#[inline(always)]` the compiler will inline all `foo_impl()` calls then use the constants to optimize the call. Nothing is guaranteed, but it should be pretty reliable (haven't tested though).

Make sure to benchmark: this can actually be a regression due to code bloat.

Comment: There is no way to generate that match expression automatically, right? I guess, I could use a macro in the worst case.

Comment: @DavidFrank Yes, you can use a macro.

Answer (score 2):

Let's use this toy example:

```
fn foo(x: u32, y: u32) -> u32 {
    x * y
}
```

```
    movl    %edi, %eax
    imull   %esi, %eax
    retq
```

But in your application, you know that `x` is very likely to be `2` every time. We can communicate that to the compiler with [`std::intrinsics::likely`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/intrinsics/fn.likely.html):

```
#![feature(core_intrinsics)]

fn foo(x: u32, y: u32) -> u32 {
    if std::intrinsics::likely(x == 2) {
        foo_impl(x, y)
    } else {
        foo_impl(x, y)
    }
}

fn foo_impl(x: u32, y: u32) -> u32 {
    x * y
}
```

```
    leal    (%rsi,%rsi), %eax
    imull   %edi, %esi
    cmpl    $2, %edi
    cmovnel %esi, %eax
    retq
```

<sup>DISCLAIMER: I'm not experienced enough to know if this is a *good* optimization or not, just that the hint changed the output.</sup>

Unfortunately while I think this is the clearest syntax, `std::intrinsics` are not stabilized. Fortunately though, we can get the same behavior using the [`#[cold]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes/codegen.html#the-cold-attribute) attribute, which is available on stable, that can convey your desire to the compiler:

```
fn foo(x: u32, y: u32) -> u32 {
    if x == 2 {
        foo_impl(x, y)
    } else {
        foo_impl_unlikely(x, y)
    }
}

fn foo_impl(x: u32, y: u32) -> u32 {
    x * y
}

#[cold]
fn foo_impl_unlikely(x: u32, y: u32) -> u32 {
    foo_impl(x, y)
}
```

```
    leal    (%rsi,%rsi), %eax
    imull   %edi, %esi
    cmpl    $2, %edi
    cmovnel %esi, %eax
    retq
```

---

I'm skeptical whether applying this to your use-case will actually yield the transformation you propose. I'd think there'd have to be a significant impact on const-propagation and even a willingness from the compiler to optimise `x < 10` into a branch of ten constants, but using the hints above will let it decide what is best.

But sometimes, you know what is best more than the compiler and can force the const-propagation by applying the transformation manually: as you've done in your original example or a different way in [@ChayimFriedman's answer](/a/75226884/2189130).